# IE6 float and height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, height, css-float

Hi i have 2 divs that floats and IE6 fails on height (its not set from css). If i have letters as g,p,j its cut off the end of these letters.

Here is the code

```
    <div class="left"> <!-- this div float left -->
    <span style="color:#666;">Legend : </span> <!--  Here the letter g is cut -->

    <a title="" class="button" href="#">Choice 1</a>
        <span class="button" style="padding-right:12px;">
            <b>Current Choice</b>
         </span>        
   </div>

   <div class="right"><!-- this div float right -->
    <span style="color:#666;">Legend 2 : 1 &nbsp; Legend3 : 1-5</span> <!--  Here the letter g is cut -->       
   </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

If i set a height at the left,right divs its working fine, but i can not know the height of the content.

Is there any other solution to make it work without set the height.

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce this in IE6. Try setting the `line-height` property of your div tags. That might help.